# iTextSharp Info Keywords Missing

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Ever since my PDF's have been updated and exported using Adobe InDesign CC 2015 (Windows) the Keywords info field is missing. Is there a fix for this? I am running iTextSharp 5.5.8. Thanks for any help in advance!

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(webRequest.DownloadData(url));                                        
 reader.Info.TryGetValue("Title", out title);
 reader.Info.TryGetValue("Keywords", out keywords);
```

[image]

Comment: Your keywords field is missing since you exported the PDFs using Adobe InDesign... what part does iTextSharp have in this? Shouldn't you fix the InDesign export process?

Comment: Why would InDesign matter? They show up when I view them in Adobe Reader. I found a solution, its related to different meta data schema's. This is for using PDFBox but the idea is the same. -> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2201